# complex stored procedure, hibernate and refresh

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, refresh

I'm working on an application which works with Hibernate and also uses stored procedures to deal with some bussiness-logic and database operations.

The problem here is that Hibernate objects don't get updated after stored procedure (sp) execution.  I understand that this is natural, and I've read that I should use session.refresh(obj) method on the entities I want to refresh (or I think that may have changed).

For simples cases I see this good, but... if the sp is quite complex and can change many entities, I think this is not feasible.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance :)